# Add the name of a model to a string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanna achieve the following to display in rails app:

```
Product instance => "product"
ProductCustomer instance => "product customer"
```

so I could do

```
<%= form_for([commentable, Comment.new]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :body, class: "form-control", id: "comment-text-area-#{commentable.id}", 
    placeholder: "Ask something about the #{commentable.class.name.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ').downcase }" %>
  ......
<% end %>
```

At the moment I'm using the following which works in all cases:

```
p = Product.new
p.class.name.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ').downcase

pc = ProductCustomer.new
pc.class.name.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ').downcase
```

My problem is that it seems to be too complex. I guess there should be a better way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ActiveModel::Naming](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html#method-c-singular) instead. Its a wonderful API for getting stuff like human names, route keys and I18n keys from model classes or instances.

> `human(options={})`
>   Transform the model name into a more humane format,
>   using I18n. By default, it will underscore then humanize the class
>   name.

```
placeholder: "Ask something about the #{ commentable.model_name.human }"
```

Note that you should provide `<label>` elements for your inputs and not just placeholder attributes [for accessibility](http://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/).

### Labels:

In Rails you frequently use [`ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder#label`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-label):

```
<%= form_for([commentable, Comment.new]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :body %>
  <%= f.text_field :body %>
<% end %>
```

Which creates a label with a `name` attribute tied to the ID of the input. However for this to work *the Rails Way* you need to let the form builder set the ID of the input.

For hiding elements I usually use the Zurb Foundation `.show-for-sr` class which basically works like in the WAI tutorial:

```
.show-for-sr {
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: max, your note regarding the label is super useful. Could you tell me which approach you usually take from that list?

Comment: max, pls also see my previous comment. In the meantime I posted another question. Could you pls take a look at it? Your answers to my questions are always outstanding and easy to understand, so would be nice to see your opinion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37303420/rails-rendering-index-in-index-with-fragment-caching

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this: `commentable.model_name.human`

In Rails calling `model_name` on an ActiveRecord model returns an instance of [ActiveModel::Name](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Name.html) which provides a useful api to interact with the model name.

Comment: I had published it a little too early, when it was an incomplete one liner. In the minute it took me to edit it, a diligent SO bee had already defrocked me :)