# rails rendering index in index with fragment caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rendering

In my rails 4 app I have comments for different models with polymorphic association. For the `post` model I display comments on the `index page`, but for `product` model I do it on the `show page`. I have problems with fine-tuning the rendering and caching on the `post index page`, since it's `comments index` in `posts index`. I provided my solutions both for the `post` version and `product` version.

I don't use `touch:true` in comment model since it doesn't make sense on the product show page. Thanks to this I don't use caching for the `posts` on the `posts index page` since the cache key would be too complex thanks to the comments.

My questions:

Is there a better way to render comments for the posts?

Is my caching strategy good enough or I should use an "outer" caching for product or post?

```
Post has_many :comments, as: :commentable
Product has_many :comments, as: :commentable
Comment belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true ###### NO touch: true
```

posts index

```
<%= render @posts %> #no caching here, key would be too complex
```

_post

```
<% cache ['post', post, post.user.profile] do %>
  <%= post.user.full_name %> #delegated from profile
  <%= post.body %>
<% end %>
<%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { commentable: post } %>
<%= render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: post.comments.ordered.includes(:user, :user_profile), as: :comment %>
```

products controller

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @product.comments.ordered.includes(:user, :user_profile)
end
```

products show

```
 <% cache [@product, @product.user.profile] do %>
   <%= product.user.full_name %> #delegated from profile
   <%= product.name %>
   <%= product.description %>
 <% end %>
 <% cache ['comments-index', @comments.map(&:id), @comments.map(&:updated_at).max,
   @comments.map{ |comment| comment.user.profile.updated_at }.max] %>
   <%= render @comments %>
 <% end %>
```

_comment (same both for product and post)

```
<% cache ['comment', comment, comment.user.profile] do %>
  <%= comment.user.full_name %> #delegated from profile
  <%= comment.body %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you read the section on [Russian Doll Caching](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#russian-doll-caching) on Rails Guides?

Comment: mysmallidea, I have.